# Grab metadata of external URL with jQuery results in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-scraping

I am trying to get the metadata of external URLs with jQuery, I am testing it with an example link from `theguardian.com`

I want to be able to get the featured image or thumbnail link so I can embed it on my site.

But I keep getting this error

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2016/jul/05/fbi-no-charges-hillary-clinton-email-investigation?format=json. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access.

This is my code

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            format: 'json'
        },
        url: 'https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2016/jul/05/fbi-no-charges-hillary-clinton-email-investigation',
        error: function() {
            console.log('there is an error');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
});
```

I have even tried with `$.get()` getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like theguardian.com doesn't allow external requests from browsers (they have to explicitly allow it). It may work outside a browser. Take a look at the info for CORS (the error you're getting): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: Oh snap! So there's no way around it?

Comment: @Halnex I can confirm requests work from outside a browser (I used `curl` to test), but other than that, no. All modern browsers respect the CORS rule, sites have to explicitly allow browser AJAX requests from other domains.

Comment: @Halnex I just used it from a cli/terminal. You could achieve the same effect with JavaScript by using Node.js to run JS outside of a browser. You could even technically create your own server in Node and call that from your browser-side script using the Node server as a sort of proxy.

Comment: I realized it is not possible so I deleted my question, but thank you for the elaboration. I've never used NodeJS before, maybe I should get into it.

Comment: @Halnex I definitely recommend it to anyone who already knows the basics of JS (looks like you do). It really opens up the possibilities for what you can do with the language when you uncouple it from the browser.